Customize RichTextPropertyEditor in DevExpress XAF Blazor EF Core
I have here in my XAF App the BusinessObject
public class ExerciseOfRights : BaseObject
{
public virtual string Title { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime? DateOfCreation { get; protected set; }
...
public virtual IList<ExerciseOfRightsDocument> Documents { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ExerciseOfRightsDocument>();
...
}

and
public class ExerciseOfRightsDocument : BaseObject
{
...
public virtual string Text {get; set; }
public virtual ExerciseOfRights ExerciseOfRights { get; set; }
...
}

The member public virtual string Text {get; set; } uses a RichTextPropertyEditor in the DetailView of the class.
This editor is a blazor component DevExpress.Blazor.RichEdit, which is adapted for XAF. This component has a Ribbon, containing a "MailMerge" Tab, which is deactivated in default in XAF.
Usualy, the Component could be customized in Blazor, Tabs can be added, the MailMerge can be connected to a DataSource. But I fail to get a solution in XAF. Has anybody a hint, how to get the solution?
Thank you,
XRobertson
I tried to implement the Blazor component directly via adaptor. But I failed to customize it in XAF. I also tried to overwrite it by public class CustomEditor:RichTextPropertyEditor, without success.
In the end I would like to add a new Tab "Insert Fields" or at least to connect the member fields of "ExerciseOfRights" with the MailMerge list of the RTF Ribbon.
